# How to jQuery validate textbox entry against value of another textbox in an asp.net grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a bulk edit `asp.net` grid for editing meter readings. The current meter reading is displayed  in a label and the user will enter the new meter reading in a textbox on the same row. I need to be able to make sure the entered reading is not less than the current meter reading in the label. I have added `CssClass` names to the label and textbox and am able to get the entered value of the textbox by attaching a function to the blur event of the textbox but I can't get the value of the label. Here is the code for the grid

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvSiteGeneratorReading" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsEquipmentMeterReadings"
    DataKeyNames="EquipmentMeterID" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>

       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Equipment Description">
            <ItemTemplate >
                <asp:Label ID="lblMeterDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MeterDescription") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Reading" SortExpression="MeterReading">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLastMeterReading"  CssClass="LastReading" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastMeterReading") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="New Reading">
           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewReadingValue"  CssClass="NewReading" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The jQuery I have so far to alert the value of the New Reading is:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {


    $(".NewReading").blur(function () {

        var enteredVal = $(this).val();
        alert(enteredVal);
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve LastMeterReading column value like this

```
$(".NewReading").blur(function () {
  var LastMeterReading = $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1)").text();                
  alert(LastMeterReading);
});
```

Comment: @Franz Sundal, After playing with your solution I found that I could reference the cell by the CssClass name rather than by the position like so:                                                                    var LastReadingDate = $.trim(($(this).closest('tr').find(".LastReadingDate").text()));

Comment: Yes when you find a row then you can search any control in that particular row